# Swift parse extend PFUser with emailVerified

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When a user is registered it needs to confirm his/hers e-mail address.
And what i am trying to achieve is, that in case the users e-mail address isn't verified the profile button is colored red, otherwise it's green.

However according to the documentation the PFUser should be extended with emailVerified.

So i was thinking in a way to use it like:

`if PFuser.currentuser.emailVerified == false`   ( however this is not available ).
Or
`if PFuser.emailVerified == false` ( however this is not possible ).

In both examples the app crashes or simply put, it's not available.

Now i also tried things like:

```
let user = PFUser
```

and then `user["emailVerified"] == false` ( but then i get string errors ).

Hope someone can assist with some advise on how to fix it :)

Comment: what value did you get in `user["emailVerified"]` ?

Comment: None, unfortunately it crashes then :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so finally i managed to figure it out with some logic after taking a break :) naise.

```
if PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("emailVerified")?.boolValue == false {
    // The rest of what you want to do comes here. 
}
```

Hopes this will help you all :) Enjoy. And thanks for all the effort guys.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered what seems like a related problem when trying to set nil values on properties of PFUser. Instead, I needed to use NSNull. You might try using an NSNumber with a value of 0 instead of false, like so:

```
let verified : NSNumber = 0
user["emailVerified"] = verified
```

Comment: `@IBAction func isUserVerified(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
            
            let verified = user["emailVerified"] as! Bool
        
            if verified == false {
                
                print("The value of verified is \(verified)")
                
            } else {
            
                print("The value of verified is \(verified)")
                
            }
            
        }`

   Now i also get an error @ as! Bool. Says unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I have tried:    `
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()
        let verified : NSNumber = 0
        user["emailVerified"] = verified
        
        print(user)`      This outputs "Cannot assign a value of type 'NSNumber' to a value of type 'AnyObjects?'.   Downcasting it as! NSNumber doesn't work also.

Comment: I'm still figuring it out people, i'll answer once solved :)